# Optimizing performance of large ASP.NET applications

Tags: asp.net, performance

I'm building a asp.net web application with lots and lots of controls and huge volumes of data. My application is very slow and it is taking a large amount of time to load the data into the .net controls like grid, tree view etc. I also have some ajaxified pages and controls in my application. I want to reduce the page load time in each postbacks.

What are the standards/best practices to be followed while developing large asp.net applications?

Thank you.

NLV

Comment: Rewrite it carefully in ASP.NET MVC and don't just load the entire database in a `DataSet` and bind it to a `GridView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Cache certain data, either in the application or in the database (thus breaking normalization but it's okay)
- Retrieve the minimum subset of data you really need. Don't pull 10000 records from the database into a grid to only display 50. Query for exactly 50.
- Mimimize the amount of server controls and dynamic markup creation. Replace what you can with passive HTML elements.
- Switch off the view state, which can potentially expand pages to many megabytes in size. Pull the data from the database on each request (in combination with caching strategies).

Comment: The second point makes good sense with a datagrid. But what if i have a tree viewer control in place of a datagrid control? I have thousands of nodes in the control. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you should only retrieve data for a node when it gets clicked to be expanded. Before that happens only load data for an upper hierarchy level. The subnodes get their data loaded on-demand (and again, only for their top-level hierarchy until their subnodes get clicked).

Answer (score 1):

You Can use JQuery to retreive the data from database which is much better than using ajax. Check this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/JsonWebServiceJQuery.aspx

Comment: So will that be fast than pulling the data using server side code?

Comment: S... Using updatepanels for dynamic loading will slow down the loading in my experience..